# Showing some random process is predictable

Tags: random-variables

I'm asked to show that given $\tau$ is a stopping time and if 
$$I_n = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}\ n\leq\tau \\
0 & \text{if}\ n>\tau
\end{cases}$$
then $(I_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a predictable process.

I know that $I_n$ is predictable if it's $\mathbb{F}_{n-1}$-measurable but I could really need some help getting through this. I was wondering if I should look at three different possibilities for the time $n$.

If $n-1\leq n\leq \tau$ it holds that $I_{n-1}=I_n=1$ and if $n>n-1>\tau$ it holds that $I_{n-1}=I_n=0$ and lastly if $n-1\leq \tau$ and $n>\tau$ it holds that $0=I_n<I_{n-1}=1$. But is this enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that $I_n = 1-1\{\tau \leq n-1\}$, and show this is $\mathbb{F}_{n-1}$-measurable.

Comparing the value of $I_n$ to $I_{n-1}$ is not enough to show that $I_n$ is $\mathbb{F}_{n-1}$-measurable (after all, how do we even know $I_{n-1}$ is $\mathbb{F}_{n-1}$-measurable?). Instead you have to show that at time $n-1$ (given the information in the sigma algebra $\mathbb{F}_{n-1}$) you can determine the value of $I_n$.

Comment: Just to make sure; when you're writing $1\{\tau\leq n-1\}$ is that the indicator function $1_{(\tau \leq n-1)}$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.